# bot framework facebook multiple pages

Tags: facebook-messenger, botframework

llhi,

I have configured Facebook connection thru Bot Framework, which has requested to configure one single Facebook page, app, and then token. Is it possible to indicate how to manage several Facebook pages thru the same Microsoft Bot Framework? If not possible, what are the available options?
Thx for your feedback,

Regards

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like a bot that works across several Facebook pages?   Do to this you'll need to create multiple registrations in the BotFramework for your bot (one for each Facebook page).  Each registration can call back to the same bot (just use the same webhook).

Comment: Hey, is it possible to automate this process? We are building a platform and need to automate the entire process.

Comment: It will require a new facebook app for each @Lars, am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

A bot can configure on multiple fanpages. I tested it, just enter new `pageId` and `PageToken` then `resubmit`. It still work well.

The problem is the UI configure `BotFramework` not display all fanpages that authorized. When click `deauthorized`, it delete all pages. We can wait dev team upgrade it or create multiple registrations like [Lars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38020895/2521404) said . I think it will work better soon.

Comment: One year later, it's still same way... so sad Microsoft =/